# Css table with fixed header and scrollable x-y body

Tags: html, css, angular5

For an angular project I need to make a table with a lot of columns. I want my header row to be visible at all time. The body of the table has to be scrollable in the x and y direction. But if I scroll in the X-position, the scrolling of the header has to come along with the rows.

This is what i've got so far. The scrollbar in the y direction is at the end of the table and is not always visible. I want the Y-scrollbar to be visible at all times. Any ideas on how to do this?

I want to achieve something like this Data Table with components [seen here](https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/data-table).

```css
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

table ,tr td{
    border:1px solid gray;
}
tbody {
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    overflow:auto;
}
thead, tbody tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
thead {
    width: calc( 100% - 1em )/* scrollbar is average 1em/16px width, remove it from thead width */
}
```

```html
<div #panel style="height: 150px; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th style="min-width: 550px;">Column1</th>
          <th style="min-width: 160px;">Column2</th>
          <th style="min-width: 80px;">Column3</th>
          <th style="min-width: 145px;">Column4</th>
          <th style="min-width: 90px;">Column5</th>
          <th style="min-width: 65px;">Column6</th>
          <th style="min-width: 65px;">Column7</th>
          <th style="min-width: 65px;">Column8</th>
          <th style="min-width: 100px;">Column9</th>
          <th style="min-width: 350px;">Column10</th>
          <th style="min-width: 360px;">Column11</th>
          <th style="min-width: 145px;">Column12</th>
          <th style="min-width: 145px;">Column13</th>
          <th style="min-width: 200px;">Column14</th>
          <th style="min-width: 200px;">Column15</th>
          <th style="min-width: 200px;">Column16</th>
          <th style="min-width: 145px;">Column17</th>
          <th style="min-width: 200px;">Column18</th>
          <th style="min-width: 200px;">Column19</th>
          <th style="min-width: 200px;">Column20</th>
          <th style="min-width: 100px;">Column21</th>
          <th style="min-width: 150px;">Column22</th>
          <th style="min-width: 150px;">Column23</th>
          <th style="min-width: 100px;">Column24</th>
      </tr>
      
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="min-width: 550px;">1</td>
          <td style="min-width: 160px;">2</td>
          <td style="min-width: 80px;">3</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">4</td>
          <td style="min-width: 90px;">5</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">6</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">7</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">8</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">9</td>
          <td style="min-width: 350px;">10</td>
          <td style="min-width: 360px;">11</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">12</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">13</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">14</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">15</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">16</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">17</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">18</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">19</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">20</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">21</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">22</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">23</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="min-width: 550px;">1</td>
          <td style="min-width: 160px;">2</td>
          <td style="min-width: 80px;">3</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">4</td>
          <td style="min-width: 90px;">5</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">6</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">7</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">8</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">9</td>
          <td style="min-width: 350px;">10</td>
          <td style="min-width: 360px;">11</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">12</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">13</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">14</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">15</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">16</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">17</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">18</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">19</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">20</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">21</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">22</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">23</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="min-width: 550px;">1</td>
          <td style="min-width: 160px;">2</td>
          <td style="min-width: 80px;">3</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">4</td>
          <td style="min-width: 90px;">5</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">6</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">7</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">8</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">9</td>
          <td style="min-width: 350px;">10</td>
          <td style="min-width: 360px;">11</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">12</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">13</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">14</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">15</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">16</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">17</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">18</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">19</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">20</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">21</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">22</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">23</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="min-width: 550px;">1</td>
          <td style="min-width: 160px;">2</td>
          <td style="min-width: 80px;">3</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">4</td>
          <td style="min-width: 90px;">5</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">6</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">7</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">8</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">9</td>
          <td style="min-width: 350px;">10</td>
          <td style="min-width: 360px;">11</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">12</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">13</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">14</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">15</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">16</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">17</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">18</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">19</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">20</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">21</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">22</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">23</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="min-width: 550px;">1</td>
          <td style="min-width: 160px;">2</td>
          <td style="min-width: 80px;">3</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">4</td>
          <td style="min-width: 90px;">5</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">6</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">7</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">8</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">9</td>
          <td style="min-width: 350px;">10</td>
          <td style="min-width: 360px;">11</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">12</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">13</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">14</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">15</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">16</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">17</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">18</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">19</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">20</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">21</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">22</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">23</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="min-width: 550px;">1</td>
          <td style="min-width: 160px;">2</td>
          <td style="min-width: 80px;">3</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">4</td>
          <td style="min-width: 90px;">5</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">6</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">7</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">8</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">9</td>
          <td style="min-width: 350px;">10</td>
          <td style="min-width: 360px;">11</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">12</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">13</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">14</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">15</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">16</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">17</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">18</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">19</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">20</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">21</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">22</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">23</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="min-width: 550px;">1</td>
          <td style="min-width: 160px;">2</td>
          <td style="min-width: 80px;">3</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">4</td>
          <td style="min-width: 90px;">5</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">6</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">7</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">8</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">9</td>
          <td style="min-width: 350px;">10</td>
          <td style="min-width: 360px;">11</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">12</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">13</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">14</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">15</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">16</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">17</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">18</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">19</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">20</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">21</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">22</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">23</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="min-width: 550px;">1</td>
          <td style="min-width: 160px;">2</td>
          <td style="min-width: 80px;">3</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">4</td>
          <td style="min-width: 90px;">5</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">6</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">7</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">8</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">9</td>
          <td style="min-width: 350px;">10</td>
          <td style="min-width: 360px;">11</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">12</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">13</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">14</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">15</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">16</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">17</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">18</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">19</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">20</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">21</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">22</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">23</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="min-width: 550px;">1</td>
          <td style="min-width: 160px;">2</td>
          <td style="min-width: 80px;">3</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">4</td>
          <td style="min-width: 90px;">5</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">6</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">7</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">8</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">9</td>
          <td style="min-width: 350px;">10</td>
          <td style="min-width: 360px;">11</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">12</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">13</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">14</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">15</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">16</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">17</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">18</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">19</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">20</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">21</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">22</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">23</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="min-width: 550px;">1</td>
          <td style="min-width: 160px;">2</td>
          <td style="min-width: 80px;">3</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">4</td>
          <td style="min-width: 90px;">5</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">6</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">7</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">8</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">9</td>
          <td style="min-width: 350px;">10</td>
          <td style="min-width: 360px;">11</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">12</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">13</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">14</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">15</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">16</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">17</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">18</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">19</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">20</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">21</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">22</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">23</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="min-width: 550px;">1</td>
          <td style="min-width: 160px;">2</td>
          <td style="min-width: 80px;">3</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">4</td>
          <td style="min-width: 90px;">5</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">6</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">7</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">8</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">9</td>
          <td style="min-width: 350px;">10</td>
          <td style="min-width: 360px;">11</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">12</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">13</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">14</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">15</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">16</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">17</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">18</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">19</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">20</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">21</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">22</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">23</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="min-width: 550px;">1</td>
          <td style="min-width: 160px;">2</td>
          <td style="min-width: 80px;">3</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">4</td>
          <td style="min-width: 90px;">5</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">6</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">7</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">8</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">9</td>
          <td style="min-width: 350px;">10</td>
          <td style="min-width: 360px;">11</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">12</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">13</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">14</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">15</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">16</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">17</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">18</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">19</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">20</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">21</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">22</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">23</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="min-width: 550px;">1</td>
          <td style="min-width: 160px;">2</td>
          <td style="min-width: 80px;">3</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">4</td>
          <td style="min-width: 90px;">5</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">6</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">7</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">8</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">9</td>
          <td style="min-width: 350px;">10</td>
          <td style="min-width: 360px;">11</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">12</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">13</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">14</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">15</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">16</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">17</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">18</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">19</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">20</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">21</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">22</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">23</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="min-width: 550px;">1</td>
          <td style="min-width: 160px;">2</td>
          <td style="min-width: 80px;">3</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">4</td>
          <td style="min-width: 90px;">5</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">6</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">7</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">8</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">9</td>
          <td style="min-width: 350px;">10</td>
          <td style="min-width: 360px;">11</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">12</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">13</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">14</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">15</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">16</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">17</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">18</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">19</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">20</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">21</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">22</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">23</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="min-width: 550px;">1</td>
          <td style="min-width: 160px;">2</td>
          <td style="min-width: 80px;">3</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">4</td>
          <td style="min-width: 90px;">5</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">6</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">7</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">8</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">9</td>
          <td style="min-width: 350px;">10</td>
          <td style="min-width: 360px;">11</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">12</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">13</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">14</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">15</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">16</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">17</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">18</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">19</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">20</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">21</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">22</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">23</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="min-width: 550px;">1</td>
          <td style="min-width: 160px;">2</td>
          <td style="min-width: 80px;">3</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">4</td>
          <td style="min-width: 90px;">5</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">6</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">7</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">8</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">9</td>
          <td style="min-width: 350px;">10</td>
          <td style="min-width: 360px;">11</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">12</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">13</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">14</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">15</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">16</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">17</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">18</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">19</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">20</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">21</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">22</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">23</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="min-width: 550px;">1</td>
          <td style="min-width: 160px;">2</td>
          <td style="min-width: 80px;">3</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">4</td>
          <td style="min-width: 90px;">5</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">6</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">7</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">8</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">9</td>
          <td style="min-width: 350px;">10</td>
          <td style="min-width: 360px;">11</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">12</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">13</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">14</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">15</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">16</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">17</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">18</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">19</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">20</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">21</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">22</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">23</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="min-width: 550px;">1</td>
          <td style="min-width: 160px;">2</td>
          <td style="min-width: 80px;">3</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">4</td>
          <td style="min-width: 90px;">5</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">6</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">7</td>
          <td style="min-width: 65px;">8</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">9</td>
          <td style="min-width: 350px;">10</td>
          <td style="min-width: 360px;">11</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">12</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">13</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">14</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">15</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">16</td>
          <td style="min-width: 145px;">17</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">18</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">19</td>
          <td style="min-width: 200px;">20</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">21</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">22</td>
          <td style="min-width: 150px;">23</td>
          <td style="min-width: 100px;">24</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for: http://ui-grid.info/

*After few attempts to make my own scrollable tables with stickly header/column I decided to use this one.*

[image]

Comment: Not really looking for a library, but thanks for the input.